# Can a voltage peak detector circuit detect square wave overshoot voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, switching-losses

I'm building a simple inverter with an inductive-capacitive load.

I wonder if I have overshoot voltage like this on my IGBT:

[image]

[image]

I want to detect this overshoot, but since I don’t have an oscilloscope I'm struggling with this issue. I'm trying to find another way to detect this overshoot and a peak detector circuit came to mind.

Can I use a peak detector circuit to detect this overshoot or can you give me a better circuit to detect this ringing overshoot?

**Note:** I don’t want to get rid this overshoot, I want to detect it by taking feedback using a current transformer and then feed it to the detector circuit because I want to use a phase lead circuit on my logic driver to get rid this overshoot, so perfect zero current switching (ZCS) can be achieved.

Comment: You ought to analyze impedance of wire , source and load and reduce them towards matching with better short cable to IGBT. This method of impedance matching is better for reducing GBW requirements of a NFB circuit

Comment: hm, why do you think this overshoot is problematic? And, how wide is your observation bandwidth?

Comment: @MarcusMüller:  The scope pictures are examples.  Maulana doesn't know if there's overshoot or not and is asking if a peak detector could be used to detect overshoot.  Maulana doesn't have a scope.

Comment: Simple inverters have complex issues with variable load and fixed reactance.  So you must analyze the rise times and RdsOn to load ratios to match them to avoid Safe Operating Area (SOA) failures with a low source impedance and conjugate reactance with filters